# Travelling to multiple countries in Schengen region

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, hungary

I am an Indian citizen in US (Tennessee) on H4 visa. I am currently a student at a college and need to travel for Budapest, Hungary and then go to Vienna, Austria, and finally to Prague, Czech Republic for a study trip. Duration of stay is 1 week each. First port of entry is Hungary.

My school has suggested me to apply for tourist visa. I am confused as to which consulate should I apply for Schengen visa ?

Comment: It's odd that your school wouldn't know, but yes a Schengen

Comment: Same length of stay, apply at first country, so Hungary. I do not know where or even who handles the application of people residing in Tennessee.

Comment: What are you going to do in those countries? If, for example, you're attending a conference in one of them, and the other stays are incidental "now that you're there" things, the one with the conference would be your main destination, and therefore the one to apply for a visa from.

Comment: @GayotFow Why? It's probably organised by a member of staff (potentially quite junior) who has little understanding of how visas etc work, and for whom most of their students can do this trip visa-free.

Answer (score 5):

You need to apply for a Schengen visa. As @Willeke mentioned, since the duration of stay in each country is the same you need to apply for the country of first entry, that's Hungary.

According to their [website](http://consulate.newyork.gov.hu/consulates-representations) Tennessee is covered by the Chicago office. I couldn't find anything on their website to suggest they accept mail-in applications, furthermore they need to collect [biometric data](http://consulate.newyork.gov.hu/visainformationeng) so it seems you'll have to travel there personally.

Answer (score 2):

You should apply for visa at the consulate of the country where you enter first. If your first port of entry is Hungary, then you should apply at the Hungarian consulate.

http://konzuliszolgalat.kormany.hu/how-to-apply-for-visa

I lived in Hungary for 5 years, traveled to Vienna and Prague like you. I suggest you plan your route like this.

Budapest -> Vienna -> Prague

Bus route very cheap i suggest orange ways from Budapest. Trains may be bit expensive but there is a direct train from Vienna to Prague.

Prague is very near to Berlin (takes 4h by train), i suggest you should squeeze some time to see Berlin amazing city.

I personally think 1 week is too much in each city, but 5 days would be more than enough.